# Return first result only for each unique result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am having some trouble with duplicating results in SQL Server 2005. I have previously used the `ROW NUMBER` function to display my query results, but I cannot get the query below to only display rownum 1:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT l.insbilleddate, l.pickupdate, l.patientname, l.inscompanyname AS Payor, l.tripid, 
l.sales, l.cost, l.sales-l.cost AS Profit, l.profitpct AS 'Profit Pct', u.pUPFName + ' ' + 
u.pUPLName AS Dispatcher, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY l.tripid ORDER BY d.trDispatchDate 
ASC) AS rownum
FROM  pUsersPrinters u
INNER JOIN TranslationDispatch d
INNER JOIN v_OLAPdataTR l ON d.trTripid = l.tripid ON u.pUP_id = d.trDispatchedBy
GROUP BY l.insbilleddate, l.pickupdate, l.patientname, l.inscompanyname, l.tripid, l.sales, 
l.cost, l.profitpct, u.pUPFName, u.pUPLName, d.trDispatchDate
HAVING l.insbilleddate >= '6/1/2014' And l.insbilleddate < '7/1/2014' AND l.cost > '0' AND 
l.profitpct < '30') q1
WHERE rownum = 1
ORDER BY q1.profitpct
```

The TranslationDispatch table adds a line each time a user dispatches a trip. If a trip needs to be reassigned the database does not overwrite the original dispatcher, instead it adds another line with the userID, tripID, and dispatch date. The `d.trTripid = l.tripid` comparison causes the trip to show for each dispatcher that marks it.

As an example, results show as:

```
TripID     trDispatchedBy    trDispatchDate
1234        Carlos            6/25/2014 10:00
1234        Tim               6/25/2014 10:02
```

...but I only want to display Carlos, as he dispatched the trip first.

EDIT: I've adjusted the query above with the help of @Vulcronos to make it work, by adding a table alias (q1) and making the `rownum = '1'` into `rownum = 1` to correctly display my final result.

Comment: Can you give me some more information about your table structure, the current results of your query, and the desired results in an edit to your question?

Comment: OK @Vulcronos , I've edited my original content. Hope this helps!

Comment: I think the problem is that you need to alias the sub select. Right before `WHERE rownum = '1'` add a name such as "Results" so the line should look like `l.profitpct < '30') Results`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try:

```
ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( PARTITION BY  l.insbilleddate, l.pickupdate, l.patientname, 
l.inscompanyname, l.tripid, l.sales, l.cost, l.profitpct, u.pUPFName, u.pUPLName, 
d.trDispatchDate ORDER BY trDispatchDate ASC)
```

This should give you a row number of one on every groups earliest dispatch date.  Then you can wrap your whole query in:

```
select *
from (my_query)
where rownum = 1
```

Comment: When I tried this, it adds a row number of 1 on each result line, causing all of the results to display anyway.

Comment: @sgriggs I used each column in the group by in the partion.  Try it with just tripdid and trDispatchedBy.

Comment: `@Vulcronos`, when I use just the tripid field in the partition, it works! The only problem I'm still having is, when I wrap the whole query as you suggested, the error states _Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'._

Comment: @sgriggs Please post your current sql in an edit to your question so I can get an idea of what is going wrong.

Comment: OK @Vulcronos... thanks for bearing with me, I think we almost have it!

Comment: @sgriggs Glad to help.  What is the error it throws?  I have two ideas.  First, rownum is a number, not a character so match 1, not '1'.  Also, I think you need a table alias.  After the closing ) give the subtable a name and use it in the where and order by clause.

Comment: Thanks @Vulcronos ! Adding the table alias and making the '1' into 1 did the trick! I will edit the final query into the question to help others. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

How about adding "TOP 1" to the outside query

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM(SELECT L.Insbilleddate, 
          L.Pickupdate, 
          L.Patientname, 
          L.Inscompanyname AS Payor, 
          L.Tripid, 
          L.Sales, 
          L.Cost, 
          L.Sales - L.Cost AS Profit, 
          L.Profitpct AS 'Profit Pct', 
          U.Pupfname + ' ' + U.Puplname AS Dispatcher, 
          ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY L.Tripid ORDER BY D.Trdispatchdate ASC)AS Rownum
     FROM Pusersprinters U
          INNER JOIN Translationdispatch D
                     INNER JOIN V_Olapdatatr L ON D.Trtripid = L.Tripid ON U.Pup_Id = D.Trdispatchedby
    GROUP BY L.Insbilleddate, 
             L.Pickupdate, 
             L.Patientname, 
             L.Inscompanyname, 
             L.Tripid, 
             L.Sales, 
             L.Cost, 
             L.Profitpct, 
             U.Pupfname, 
             U.Puplname, 
             D.Trdispatchdate
    HAVING L.Insbilleddate >= '6/1/2014'
       AND L.Insbilleddate < '7/1/2014'
       AND L.Cost > '0'
       AND L.Profitpct < '30') A
 ORDER BY A.Profitpct;
```

Comment: it still gives me the _Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'_ error.

Comment: Just removed the where clause and change the alias on the order by